# SqlAlchemy UPDATE that has a FROM that is an inline SELECT rather than an explicit table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

How can I use [SQLAlchemy Core API (aka SQLAlchemy Expression Language)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/tutorial.html) to execute a SQL UPDATE that has a FROM that is an inline SELECT rather than an explicit table?

For example, how can I express the following query using SQLAlchemy instead of sql strings?

```
UPDATE data
SET invalid = True 
FROM (
    SELECT data.person_id as inner_col 
    FROM data
    LEFT JOIN people
    ON people.id = data.person_id
    WHERE people.id IS NULL
) inner_query
WHERE inner_query.inner_col = data.person_id
```

I'd like to be able to dynamically construct queries like this with variables for the table names and column names, and I'd like to use SQLAlchemy Expression Language to prevent against [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I also hope that SQLAlchemy will result in more maintainable code than a bunch of string concatenation (especially if the number of columns we are joining on in the inner query is a dynamic list etc.).

---

For reference, here is a complete example which I'd love to have the same behavior without using `sqlalchemy.text`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sqlalchemy

# create and connect to in memory database 
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite://') 
metadata_obj = sqlalchemy.MetaData()
people = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'people', metadata_obj,
    sqlalchemy.Column('id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column('name', sqlalchemy.String),
)
data = sqlalchemy.Table(
    'data', metadata_obj,
    sqlalchemy.Column('person_id', sqlalchemy.Integer),
    sqlalchemy.Column('data_foo', sqlalchemy.String),
    sqlalchemy.Column('invalid', sqlalchemy.Boolean),
)
metadata_obj.create_all(engine)
conn = engine.connect()

def create_records():
    conn.execute(people.insert().values(id=1, name='Mary'))
    conn.execute(people.insert().values(id=2, name='James'))

    conn.execute(data.insert().values(person_id=1, data_foo='good foo', invalid=None))
    conn.execute(data.insert().values(person_id=42, data_foo='chop suey', invalid=None))

def dynamic_update(referenced_table, referenced_column, referencing_table, referencing_column):
    sql = f"""
UPDATE {referencing_table}
SET invalid = True 
FROM (
    SELECT {referencing_table}.{referencing_column} as inner_col 
    FROM {referencing_table}
    LEFT JOIN {referenced_table}
    ON {referenced_table}.{referenced_column} = {referencing_table}.{referencing_column}
    WHERE {referenced_table}.{referenced_column} IS NULL
) inner_query
WHERE inner_query.inner_col = {referencing_table}.{referencing_column}
    """
    conn.execute(sqlalchemy.text(sql))
    

def print_records(msg):
    print(f'{msg}:')
    print("  people:")
    for person in conn.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.select(people)):
        print('    ', person)
    print("  data:")
    for datum in conn.execute(sqlalchemy.sql.select(data)):
        print('    ', datum)
    print()

create_records()
print_records('initial values')
dynamic_update(
    referenced_table="people",
    referenced_column="id",
    referencing_table="data",
    referencing_column="person_id",
)
# Instead of passing strings, I really want to do:
# dynamic_update(people, people.c.id, data, data.c.person_id)
print_records('after update')
```

And here is the output when run with python 3.9 and sqlalchemy 1.4.36:

```
initial values:
  people:
     (1, 'Mary')
     (2, 'James')
  data:
     (1, 'good foo', None)
     (42, 'chop suey', None)

after update:
  people:
     (1, 'Mary')
     (2, 'James')
  data:
     (1, 'good foo', None)
     (42, 'chop suey', True)
```

Comment: I think your update statement is unnecessarily complex and that it can simplified to `UPDATE data SET invalid = True WHERE data.person_id IS NULL` this should make translation into SqlAlchemy easier I suspect

Comment: @PaulMaxwell that simplification changes the behavior -- I need to join two tables -- my example is setting `invalid = True` when the foreign key reference is invalid (not when it is just null).

Comment: `foreign key reference is invalid` ok, perhaps the data model needs to implement some constraints to ensure data integrity

Comment: @PaulMaxwell for my use case the purpose is to find data that doesn't conform to a list of rules, and not to just reject data that is non-conforming. I agree with that for most other use cases that a foreign key constraint would make more sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def dynamic_update(referenced_table, referenced_column, referencing_table, referencing_column):
    valid_referenced_values = sqlalchemy.sql.select(referenced_column)
    conn.execute(referencing_table.update().\
        where(referencing_column.not_in(valid_referenced_values)).\
        values(invalid=True))
```

SqlAlchemy executes this expression as the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE data
SET invalid=?
WHERE (data.person_id NOT IN (SELECT people.id FROM people))
```

Comment: but if `data.person_id` actually is NULL then will that `NOT IN`  will correctly?

Comment: @PaulMaxwell for my use case that doesn't matter